# How does the satisfaction work with partial orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm a little bit confused about the precedence relation corresponding to partial orders; to be specific, let's say $P_{1} \preceq P_{2}$ which means $P_{1}$ is stronger than $P_{2}$ iff $P_{1} \wedge P_{2} = P_{1}$.

The source of ambiguity is the following predicate-based derivation of above implication as follows:

$P_{1}$ is stronger than $P_{2}$ iff $(\forall x) (x \models P_{1} \Longrightarrow x \models P_{2})$.

I can't understand $(\forall x) (x \models P_{1} \Longrightarrow x \models P_{2})$; to me, since $P_{1}$ is stronger than $P_{2}$ the implication should be something like $(\forall x) (x \models P_{2} \Longrightarrow x \models P_{1})$ because $P_{2}$ basically includes $P_{1}$.

Probably this confusion stems from the fact that I'm interpreting the meet operation ($\wedge$) as the same thing similar to the intersection operation ($\cap$).

Any help?

Comment: The implication is in the right direction; a stronger statement is true of fewer objects $x$.  For example, "$x$ is a resident of Ohio" is a stronger statement than "$x$ is a resident of the United States", because the first statement gives you more information about $x$ than the second. And the first statement is true of fewer $x$'s than the second.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Your comment is a little bit vague as it's not clear what you mean by the `first` and the `second` statement.

Comment: The first statement is the statement that is earlier in my comment, and the second is the one that is later. The first is "$x$ is a resident of Ohio" and the second is "$x$ is a resident of the United States."